# Live Reload Over a Networked Drive

Tags: stylus, network-drive, livereload, codekit, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to use CodeKit, LiveReload, or grunt watch to immediately see changes from files on a networked drive.  It take about 7 seconds for the compilation of my Stylus file to complete and another 10-20 seconds for them to display in the browser.

Is there any way to speed up the responsiveness of my site other than moving it onto my local hard drive?